# Xpath to parse the background image url from a style tag

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="card-image" style="background-image: url("https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-0kvv9/images/stencil/500x659/products/170691/242554/dicemastgreenflash__36803.1503934716.jpg?c=2");">
</div>
```

When I input this,

```
.//*[@class='card-image']/@style
```

it returns this:

```
background-image:url('https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-0kvv9/images/stencil/500x659/products/170691/242554/dicemastgreenflash__36803.1503934716.jpg?c=2');
```

I only want it to return the URL.

Comment: <div class="card-image" style="background-image: url("https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-0kvv9/images/stencil/500x659/products/170691/242554/dicemastgreenflash__36803.1503934716.jpg?c=2");">
</div>

Comment: What is your environment? Where do you input this?

Comment: Was your question answered?  If so, please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) the answer.  If not, please comment and explain in what way your question is not answered.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
substring-before(substring-after(.//*[@class='card-image']/@style, "url('"), ");")
```

will select only the URL, as requested.